# How provider can gets informashion about sharing internet through Wi-Fi adapter?

Tags: wifi, hardware, network-protocols, provider

I know about **TTL**. If there is some adapter then TTL -= 1. There are some other ways to get information about Wi-Fi adapter?

And if i want to hide information about using Wi-Fi i must disable dicrement TTL in firmware of router? Thats all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TTL is not enough information to determine if you use wifi. TTL is configurable and you can change it easily in your PC no need to hack the AP.

for windows 7:

1. run regedit
2. open HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters
3. add DWORD 32-bit name it defaultTTL and set any value from the range [0-255]

for other os google knows how to, you just need to ask.

there is no way the provider can know you use a wifi adapter. Unless physicly coming to your place and discovering wifi network.